# how to increment value of string variable?

Tags: java, static

I have to increment the variable count and return as 001, 002...,099....,999  The update() returns the count value and reset() will resets the static variable
The code i have used it.

```
public class getCount {
static String count="0";
//resets the value to 0
public static void reset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    count="0";
}
//updates the value
public static String update() {
    String temp=count;
    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("000");
    String T=String.valueOf(df1.format(Integer.parseInt(temp)));    
    if( temp=="1000")
    {
        count="1";
        return count;
    }
    return T;
}

//main() is used for testing    
public static void main(String[] a) {
    String c1=update();
    System.out.println(c1);

    String c2=update();
    System.out.println(c2);

    String c3=update();
    System.out.println(c3);

    String c4=update();
    System.out.println(c4);

    String c5=update();
    System.out.println(c5);

    reset();
    String c6=update();
    System.out.println(c6);
    String c7=update();
    System.out.println(c7);
    String c8=update();
    System.out.println(c8);
}
```

The output I'm getting is 001,001....

Comment: After you figure out the new string, ( `String T=String.valueOf(df1.format(Integer.parseInt(temp)));` ), you don't store it anywhere. Also, `if( temp=="1000")` isn't going to work: use `.equals()`.

Comment: In addition to the excellent khelwood's comment, why do you store your counter as a `String` ? An `int` should be enough here, and much more efficient :)

Comment: I don't see you incrementing anything. Change the line where you set `String T` to `String T=String.valueOf(df1.format(Integer.parseInt(temp) + 1));`

Comment: @khelwood Thanks.. But its not working :(

Comment: @Nizil Yeah.. int will serve my purpose .. but I have to return it as 001 , 002, and so on after incrementing

Comment: @Anjanasuresh Your `update()` method will always return `String`, but `count` may be an `int`. You just have to return `String.format("%03d", count)` or `df1.format(count).toString()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit simpler :

```
public class Count {

    private static int count = 0;

    // resets the value to 0
    public static void reset() {
        count = 0;
    }

    // updates the value
    public static String update() {
        count++;
        if(count == 1000) count = 1;
        return String.format("%03d", count);
    }

    // main() is used for testing
    public static void main(String[] a) {

        for(int i=0; i< 1001; i++){
            String c1 = update();
            System.out.println(c1);
        }

        reset();

        String c2 = update();
        System.out.println(c2);

        String c3 = update();
        System.out.println(c3);


    }
}
```

By the way, your class name `getCount` should be `GetCount` and even better (in my opinion), with no verb : `Count`